# Rails - Model with attributes, which are not stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, attributes

The whole project is build like that: I've got an api which provides data and saves data. Than another Application which converts the data of the data api into "nice and clean" data. and than a frontend, which takes the nice and clean data.

In the Middle part, I got the Model Field. It has multiple Attributes like: id, area, etc. those attributes are also in the schema.rb. Now I also have attributes like: field_nr which are not in the schema.rb. But taken from the api, converted and then printed as json. Now I have to read from the field model the attribute field_nr, which is not in the schema.rb/database. How can I read those attributes?

Thanks for your help & just ask if something is unclear

Comment: Change field to field_nr using the api.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby instance variables are always private*. And you provide access by creating accessors:

```
class Thing
  attr_reader :a_readable_attr
  attr_setter :a_write_only_attr
  attr_accessor :a_rw_attribute
end
```

This is equivilent to:

```
class Thing
  def a_readable_attr
    @a_readable_attr
  end

  def a_write_only_attr=(v)
    @a_write_only_attr = v
  end
  
  def a_rw_attribute
    @a_rw_attribute
  end

  def a_rw_attribute=
    @a_rw_attribute
  end
end
```

<del>Adding "virtual" attributes to an ActiveRecord model is pretty much just like adding attributes to any other Ruby class.</del>

While this was true when the answer was written in 2014 today you you would use `ActiveRecord::Attributes` and `ActiveModel::Attributes` for non ActiveRecord models:

```
class Thing < ApplicationRecord
  attribute :foo, :string
  attribute :bar, :float, default: 1.0
end

class VirtualThing
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attribute :foo, :string
  attribute :bar, :float, default: 1.0
end
```

This gives you typecasting, defaults, serialization etc which you won't get with `attr_accessor`.

Answer (score 0):

As an option, you can add `attr_accessor  :field_nr` into model class. This will give you needed setters and getters.